# Convert a JSON response to a 2D matrix in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

I am trying to convert a JSON response to a matrix in a specific way, as in the below image, but didn't figure it out.

[image: The expected output matrix]

The JSON response i used.

```json
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
      "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
      "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {
          "id": "42",
          "type": "people"
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [{
    "type": "people",
    "id": "42",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 80,
      "gender": "male"
    }
  }]
}
```

I tried the following code but not getting the expected result.

```js
const response = JSON.parse({
  here i used the json response
});
var arr = Object.entries(response);
var row = 1;
var col = 4;
console.log(arr[row - 1][col + 1])
```

Comment: What is the desired data structure result? The image is nice, but it doesn't tell us what the underlying data structure is. Please provide it in JavaScript syntax.

Comment: the image output is not in JavaScript, I am tring to figure out the structure to get the same reuslt in JavaScript.
I dont have access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can "flatten" your object with a recursive function like this:

```js
function flatten(obj, key='', out={}) {
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        let kr = key ? key + '.' + k : k
        if (typeof v === 'object' && v)
            flatten(v, kr, out)
        else
            out[kr] = v
    }
    return out
}

//


res = {
    "data": [{
        "type": "articles",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!",
            "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
            "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
            "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "author": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "42",
                    "type": "people"
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    "included": [{
        "type": "people",
        "id": "42",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "John",
            "age": 80,
            "gender": "male"
        }
    }]
}


console.log(flatten(res))
```

Comment: I tried it, and added these to lines : 
`var arr = Object.entries(response);

console.log(arr)

![getting this output][https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoCLZ.png]

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Create a function to flatten an object;
2. Call it on each entry of the `data` and `including` arrays.
3. Build a 2 dimensional array from that, including the headings (keys)
4. Convert that matrix to HTML, converting ISO date strings to a different date format

Here is a snippet:

```js
function* flatten(obj) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (Object(value) === value) {
            for (let [key2, value2] of flatten(value)) {
                yield [`${key}.${key2}`, value2];
            }
        } else yield [key, value];
    }
}

// Convert ISO format date to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format (UTC)
function format(value) {
    return String(value).replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d).*/,
                                 "$3/$2/$1 $4:$5:$6");    
}

function makeMatrix(obj) {
    const heading = [];
    const matrix = [heading];
    for (const elem of Object.values(obj).flat()) {
        const row = [];
        for (const [key, value] of flatten(elem)) {
            let col = heading.indexOf(key);
            if (col < 0) col = heading.push(key) - 1;
            row[col] = value;
        }
        matrix.push(row);
    }
    // Fill gaps
    return matrix.map(row => 
        heading.map((_, i) => row[i] ?? "")
    );
}

function toHTML(matrix) {
    return `<table>${
        matrix.map((row, i) => `<tr>${
            row.map(cell => `<t${"dh"[+!i]}>${format(cell) ?? ""}</t${"dh"[+!i]}>`)
               .join("")
        }</t>`).join("")
    }</table>`;
}

// Your data
const response = {"data": [{"type": "articles","id": "1","attributes": {"title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!","body": "The shortest article. Ever.","created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z","updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"},"relationships": {"author": {"data": {"id": "42","type": "people"}}}}],"included": [{"type": "people","id": "42","attributes": {"name": "John","age": 80,"gender": "male"}}]};
const matrix = makeMatrix(response);
const htmlTable = toHTML(matrix);
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = htmlTable;
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td, th { border: 1px solid; white-space: nowrap }
```

```html
<div></div>
```